# Android Studio Kotlin Intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    btnLogin.setOnClickLister {
        val intent = Intent(this, homemenu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
} }
```

[image: The Photo of the code]

I have set the button for the Intent function. But it is still an error how can I fix this. The task I just only want the button after click it will head to another activity. appreciate for helping

Comment: The error message explains itself. Where did you get `btnLogin`? It is not defined.

Comment: You need to use [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#findViewById(int)) or [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because btnLogin is not defined.

You should define btnLogin (from activity_main xml)

```
val btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin) as Button
```

Rest is good.

Comment: Sounds good.

You can define like this, too.

lateinit var btnLogin: Button

onCreated(..) {}